# IntelliJ, select first few rows datasource view

Tags: intellij-idea

Is there any way to select the first few rows of a table in intelliJ datasource view ?

In mysql workbench you can right click and see the first 1000 rows instead of typing the command `select * from...`, which is really handy. So is there this possibility ? I'm not finding it

Comment: Doesnt it show the first 500 by default?

Comment: @vikingsteve On intellij ?

Comment: Yes if you double click the table name in the list....

Comment: @vikingsteve Yeah I didn't try that for some reason and I didn't find it in the doc. If you want to answer I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just double click the table in the list view for the DataSource, it will show the first (x) lines where I believe x by default is 500.